# xpath xml files within matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to read,compare and look for a specefic strings in xml files using xpath from Matlab ?
I don't find any documentation.

could someone give me an example ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
 <lists name="myState">
         <description name="-temp">-20</description>
         <description name="localization">north</description>  
         <description name="-state">false</description> 
  </lists>
</address>  
<language language="english" name=""> 
     <description name="population">5000</description> 
</language>
```

here to access to description name="localization"> , I did :

```
docNode = xmlread(myXMLFILE);
factory = XPathFactory.newInstance;
xpath = factory.newXPath;

% compile and evaluate the XPath Expression
 expression = xpath.compile(adress/lists/description')
description = expression.evaluate(docNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
descriptionValue = phoneNumberNode.getTextContent  % this gives me -20
```

how can I get the value of  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Google? One of the first link gave me a good example of using XPath on FileExchange:

[Using XPath from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31382-using-xpath-from-matlab)

> An XPath package started shipping as part of Java 5, so we can use it
>   from MATLAB. This is a simple example.
>
> [The Java XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) tutorial on ibm.com is a good introduction to XPath
>   in Java.

```
% Import the XPath classes
import javax.xml.xpath.*

% Construct the DOM.
doc = xmlread(which('demos/demos.xml'));

% Create an XPath expression.
factory = XPathFactory.newInstance;
xpath = factory.newXPath;
expression = xpath.compile('//demosection/label');

% Apply the expression to the DOM.
nodeList = expression.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);

% Iterate through the nodes that are returned.
for i = 1:nodeList.getLength
    node = nodeList.item(i-1);
    disp(char(node.getFirstChild.getNodeValue))
end
```

---

Another good article is in Mike's blog - [XML and MATLAB: Navigating a Tree](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/). It has a part specifically on using XPath.

Comment: hello yuk, I've updated my question by pointing the example of xml file and  the code trying to access to nodes , could you help please ?